# How do you fill out a google docs form via POST if the program needs to log into a google account?

Tags: c#, forms, google-api

I've seen plenty of posts on how to fill out a google form via POST or GET. What I'm wondering now is how you can do that with a form that requires you to log in with a google account. I can't just go to the URL of my form and fill it out, I must log in first.

I checked out OAuth2, and API access. However I am not sure if I'm looking in the right place to find a solution.

The meat of the question is, how do I get my program to "log into" google to access a form I want to fill out.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Edit: I've been digging through google's Dev documents. I'm finding a significant number of general guidelines, but nothing solid that explicitly tells you how to auth. I may be going about this the wrong way, I feel like I'm just flaying around and finding answers above my level of Google API understanding.